# How to change classes with selected area in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make calendar like tables,

In my code,I would like to register event.

My desired result is when I click `2` and then click `5`, the class of `2` to `5` will be changed. 
and `first` to `hovered` cells will become aqua.

So that I defined `first` variable , But I feel like I must also define`second`variables.

Are there any solutions?

Thanks

```js
var first;

$("td").on('click', function(){
  first = this.id;
 });
 


$("td").hover(function() {
    const id = Number($(this).attr('id'));
      $("table td").removeClass("aqua");


    for(var j = first;j <= id; j++){
      $("#"+j).addClass("aqua");
    }
  });
  
    $("td").on('click', function(){
  second = this.id;
 });
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
  <td id="11">11</td>
  <td id="12">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if one selects 12 first and than 1? What about hover? What should happen with hover while only one is selected? What about deselection? What about subsequent selections? What about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Calendars have semantically almost nothing (besides day-of-week) to do with tabular data. Instead of `<table>` it's easier to use `<div>`s.
- Selection and hover state cannot go in the same basket.
- Your problem is a bit more complicated that you thought, create a **range** Array what will hold the **sorted** *min* and *max* values of a selection.
- Use `.slice(start, end)` to get the desired Elements for highlight.
- classNames should be color agnostic. Use rather `is-active` and `is-hover`

```js
function CalendarSelection() {

  const $days = $(this).find('.d.m_this');
  const range = [-1, -1];

  const $daysRange = rng => {
    rng.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return $days.slice(rng[0], rng[1] + 1);
  }

  function hoverRange(ev) {
    if (range[0] < 0 || (range[0] > -1 && range[1] > -1)) return; // Do nothing
    $days.removeClass('is-hover');
    if (ev.type === 'mouseleave') return; // Stop here, it's a mouseleave.
    $daysRange([range[0], $days.index(this)]).addClass('is-hover');
  }

  function activeRange() {
    $days.removeClass('is-active is-hover');

    if (range[0] > -1 && range[1] > -1) { // RESET
      range[0] = -1;
      range[1] = -1;
    }

    if (range[0] > -1 && range[1] < 0) { // SET END
      range[1] = $days.index(this);
      $daysRange(range).addClass('is-active');
    }

    if (range[0] < 0 && range[1] < 0) { // SET START
      range[0] = $days.index(this);
      $daysRange([range[0], range[0]]).addClass('is-active');
    }
  }

  $days.on({
    click: activeRange,
    mouseenter: hoverRange,
    mouseleave: hoverRange,
  });
}

// Apply to all .calendar on page
$(".Calendar").each(CalendarSelection);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

.Calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 260px;
}

.Calendar>* {
  flex: 0 0 14.28%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.Calendar .wd {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Calendar .d.m_this {
  transition: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Calendar .d.m_this.is-hover {
  background: hsl(180, 70%, 90%);
}

.Calendar .d.m_this.is-active {
  background: hsl(200, 70%, 80%);
}

.Calendar .d.m_this:hover {
  background: hsl(180, 70%, 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="Calendar">
  <div class="wd">MO</div>
  <div class="wd">TU</div>
  <div class="wd">WE</div>
  <div class="wd">TH</div>
  <div class="wd">FR</div>
  <div class="wd">SA</div>
  <div class="wd">SU</div>

  <div class="d m_prev"></div>
  <div class="d m_prev"></div>
  <div class="d m_this">1</div>
  <div class="d m_this">2</div>
  <div class="d m_this">3</div>
  <div class="d m_this">4</div>
  <div class="d m_this">5</div>
  <div class="d m_this">6</div>
  <div class="d m_this">7</div>
  <div class="d m_this">8</div>
  <div class="d m_this">9</div>
  <div class="d m_this">10</div>
  <div class="d m_this">11</div>
  <div class="d m_this">12</div>
  <div class="d m_this">13</div>
  <div class="d m_this">14</div>
  <div class="d m_this">15</div>
  <div class="d m_this">16</div>
  <div class="d m_this">17</div>
  <div class="d m_this">18</div>
  <div class="d m_this">19</div>
  <div class="d m_this">20</div>
  <div class="d m_this">21</div>
  <div class="d m_this">22</div>
  <div class="d m_this">23</div>
  <div class="d m_this">24</div>
  <div class="d m_this">25</div>
  <div class="d m_this">26</div>
  <div class="d m_this">27</div>
  <div class="d m_this">28</div>
  <div class="d m_this">29</div>
  <div class="d m_this">30</div>
  <div class="d m_this">31</div>
  <div class="d m_next"></div>
  <div class="d m_next"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```